# Setting up Git, first push - Permission Denied?

Tags: git, bitbucket

My first time with Git, opened an account with bitbucket, and followed their directions:

```
mkdir /path/to/your/project
cd /path/to/your/project
git init
git remote add origin https://benzle@bitbucket.org/benzle/tutorials.git
echo "Kyle Benzle" >> contributors.txt
git add contributors.txt
git commit -m 'Initial commit with contributors'
git push -u origin master
```

At the last line, "push" I get a fatal error, "Please make sure you have the correct access rights".

This is where Git should be asking for my password right? What might I be missing, thank you.

Comment: you can probably accomplish what you want with the [SendText](https://github.com/wch/SendText) plugin but it won't be as seamless/integrates as RStudio is.

Comment: Yes, that is pretty much what I am doing now, but really like Rstudio's ability to save my whole script and then send only selected code.